# How to check if the voucher has already been used

Tags: php, foreach, discount

I came across in a looping confusion, actually, I'm trying to check, 
**First Condition:** if voucher type is `AMOUNT = AMOUNT` and `value > 0 and $totalRules <= 1` means this is the first time if user is using the coupson then let the user to use it.
**Second condition:** I'm checking if `AMOUNT = AMOUNT` and `value > 0  and $totalRules >=1` means the user has already used the coupon.

**Thrid Condition:** if `AMOUNT !=AMOUNT` and `$totalRules >=1` means  this time a user pick a different coupon, that could be PERCENT type then we are not allowing user to use this coupon.

Now, for the first time, the code is working fine but if refresh the page the other conditions are getting true even though I used `break;`

Could anyone please help me to sort this issue? I know I need to improve that code, I need seniors help.

```
    $vDetail = array('AMOUNT', 'ONLY'); // For now check if the coupon type is AMOUNT (set from admin)
    $voucherAllowed = 1; // Total number of voucher allowed, Global variable.
    $totalRules = 1; // First tiem it'll be 0, then always adds 1 in that variable to check if user has already used any coupon.
    $voucherTypeArray ['AMOUNT'] = 8.00; 
    $voucherTypeArray ['PERCENT'] = 0.00;



foreach($voucherTypeArray as $thisVoucher => $vValue )
{
    echo "$vDetail[0] == $thisVoucher && $vValue>0 &&  $totalRules <= $voucherAllowed <br>";
    if($vDetail[0]==$thisVoucher && $vValue>0 && (int)$totalRules <= $voucherAllowed)
    { $throwError = '0'; break; } // Continue to the next rule and add this one.
    elseif($vDetail[0]==$thisVoucher && $vValue > 0 && (int)$totalRules >= $voucherAllowed)
    {
        $throwError = "Only $voucherAllowed voucher can be redeem at this time.";
        break;
    }
    elseif($vDetail[0]!=$thisVoucher && (int)$totalRules >= $voucherAllowed)
    {
        $throwError = 'aYou cannot redeem this voucher at this time.';
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your first and second condition can both be `true` at the same time, if `$totalRules == 1`.

Comment: @AlexP so do you think, I should not use comparison operator which is <=

Comment: "I need seniors" made my day.

Comment: Heres the PHP Fiddle:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fnn-qrw

Comment: `$voucher['AMOUNT']` and `$voucher['PERCENT']` are undefined?

Comment: Not entirely sure but this `foreach($voucherTypeArray as $thisVoucher => $vValue )` shouldn't  `=>` be `->` ? as in `foreach($voucherTypeArray as $thisVoucher -> $vValue )` @Nadeem

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I see with your code:

```
if($vDetail[0]==$thisVoucher && $vValue>0 && (int)$totalRules <= $voucherAllowed)
```

`$vDetail` is not an array yet you are accessing it as such.

This means it will treat `$vDetail` as if it were an array of characters (in this case taking the first letter `A`). Ensure this is what you mean to do (your code is effectively comparing: `$voucher['AMOUNT'] == 'A'`).

And your conditionals do not take into account `$totalRules == 1`

Comment: `$vDetail` **is** an array, take another look `$vDetail[0] == 'AMOUNT'`

Comment: @AlexP no `$voucher['AMOUNT']=8;` and `$voucher['PERCENT']=0.0`
It's in array

PHP-FIDDLE: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3g2-4vj

Comment: @AlexP: The question was edited after my answer to make it an array. Please check the edit history. If that's why you downvoted, please undo it. Thanks!

Comment: @webbiedave Ah my bad sorry, the down-vote however is apparently locked in for some reason